# How do I prevent a specific Google Drive folder syncing to my computer?

Tags: google-drive

Is there anyway to only keep pics on the cloud drive and not a copy on my computer?

Comment: you can't but please vote at https://connect.googleforwork.com/ideas/6973 to let them know we want it.

Answer (score 14):

There are two basic ways.

1. Don't use the Google Drive desktop app. Just upload your files to Google Drive using the web interface.
2. If you want to be able to sync some files, but not all, you can define which folders under Google Drive should be included/excluded.

   Simply right-click the Google Drive app. Check "Only sync some folders to this computer". Then check the folders that you want to sync. Files that are in unchecked folders will not be synced. After that, you can delete your local copies and the files in the cloud will be unaffected.

   (To prevent accidentally losing files, I would create the folder in the Google Drive interface first, and leave it empty. Then use the Google Drive app to exclude that folder from syncing. Then upload the photo files to the folder on the web.)

Comment: #2 only works for top level folders..

Comment: At least for Google Drive on Mac, you no longer need to delete the folders after. They will delete automatically. And it works with subfolders. You will, however, need to clear out your trash after it finishes deleting.

Comment: This answer seems out of date?

Comment: This might also take another direction, probably leading to a 3rd solution using permissions. For example, I am using special file and folder permissions (currently at the root level on my machine) for the resources that I don't want Google's Backup and Sync to have access to. This works OK, since the App cannot touch these files but it can get kind of tricky when one wants to easily set and modify the files from a special account. For me, this is not very practical, but it turned out to be my last resort.

Comment: @KostasX That sounds like a good solution. But I could not find out how to block software from accessing a folder under Windows 10. Can you give instructions how to do it? Maybe even post it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: @KaiNoack I am afraid it's been some time since I've last touched roles and permissions on a Windows system so I cannot help you on that. I am currently on a Mac. I'm pretty sure you can get all the information you need by doing a little search on Google.