# Why can't I keep local Google docs to use offline when using syncing?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, synchronization

I want to sync *most* of my files. But there are some files that I don't want to sync up to the Google server. But I still want the ability to open them locally on my hard drive via the local Google browser which would open them in Google format they were created with.

It seems Google only gives you 3 choices:

1. sync them and have available on both sides,
2. delete files if you don't want them to sync,
3. keep the files on the server side only.

**How do you reverse option #3 by keeping locally only, but NOT on their server side?**
Seems they don't allow that option?

Comment: Google Drive doesn't support that. See also: [Can Google Drive behave more like DropBox or OneDrive](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/79445/354)

Answer (score 1):

Google doesn't have offline editor as of now as a standalone app. So you have to use online editor only. But using Chrome you can view and edit files offline. [Check it out.](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to open Google Drive files **locally** it's required to sync them. The alternatives are:

1. Use [Google Drive for your Mac/PC](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2374987?hl=en). This will not allow to edit files in Google formats while offline, but while online this will open the files in Google formats in the browser.
2. Use [Google Drive, Docs, Sheets & Slides offline](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en). Require Chrome. It's not intended to be used with the OS file manager to browse the folders and files. It doesn't allow to choose which folders will be synced.
3. Use [Google Drive app for Android/iOS](https://support.google.com/drive#topic=2375071). This requires a supported mobile device or an Android/iOS emulator (the use of emulators is not supported by Google).